# How to end/stop item edit in Flex DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, datagrid, air

Normally, you update the data bound to a datagrid item like this:

```
    protected function onGridEditEnd(event:DataGridEvent):void
    {
        if (grid.dataProvider != null && event != null)
        {
            var editor:Object = event.currentTarget.itemEditorInstance;

            if (event.columnIndex == getColumnIndex(columnA) {
                    collection[event.rowIndex].name = TextInput(editor).text;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `itemEditEnd` event is dispatched right after the user finishes editing.
So, what if I want to

1. End the edit (from another method or handler other than `itemEditEnd` handler)
2. Update the value of the bound data item at the same time.

**"while"** the item is being edited by the user.

For example; how do I trigger this from a `keyDown` event handler?

Note: You could call `onGridEditEnd(null)` which would end the edit but not update the data. `onGridEditEnd(new DataGridEvent(DataGridEvent.ITEM_EDIT_END, ...))` would work but you also need to store and pass values like columnIndex, rowIndex, dataField, etc.. which does not seem to be the best and simplest way.

thanks...

Comment: I would have recommended your second approach; create a hard coded event" and dispatch it manually.

Comment: What Jeff said, and I'll add... if you want better control, get rid of the item editors completely, and use ItemRenderers with appropriate states. It much easier to control and feels more natural to use.

Comment: seems there is no other proper way.. I had to use my second approach.. thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1):

try setting `editable` property to false (then you can turn it back on).
Or you could try setting focus (`FocusManager.focus = null`) elsewhere. This way it will be still editable, but the user will have to click it again.